# How to append json objects in JQuery inside dynamically created rows

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to Jquery and Json. 
I dynamically created this html after ajax success happens.

```
<itemsdiv>
    <item> 
      <row>
         <div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
       <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
       <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
    </item>
    <item> 
       <row>
         <div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
       <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
       <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
       </row>
    </item>
</itemsdiv>
```

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "main.aspx/GetRooms",
                data: "{'arrival':'" + arrival + "','departure':'" + departure + "','nob':'" + nob + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {                    

                var e = $('<div id="itemsdiv"></div>');

                    $('#step-1 .col-md-12').append(e);

                    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);
                    var length = 0;              
                    for (var key in result) {
                      if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            length++;
                            $item= $('<div class="item" />').attr('id', 'room' + length);
                            $('#itemsdiv').append($item);

                            var id= result[key].ID;
                            var title= result[key].Title;
                            var price= result[key].Price;
                     }

                    }
                    for (var x = 0; x < 3; x = x + 1) {
                        $row = $('<div class="row" />');
                        $('.item').append($row);
                    }

                    $colx = $("<div class='col-xs-12'></div>");
                    $('.item'.row').append($colx);

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("err");
                }
            });
```

I couldn't figure out how to put json values that return from db to the according places inside divs. Like this order:

```
 <itemsdiv>
        <item> 
          <row>
             <div class=col-xs-12> title bla </div>
           </row>
           <row><div class=col-xs-12> Price 10$ </div>
           </row>
           <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
           </row>
        </item>
        <item> 
           <row>
             <div class=col-xs-12> title bla bla</div>
           </row>
           <row><div class=col-xs-12> Price 100$ </div>
           </row>
           <row><div class=col-xs-12></div>
           </row>
        </item>
    </itemsdiv>
```

Comment: I'm trying to fix the conglomerate mess and post a possible solution, but it's very confusing. First of all, where does `$room` come from? What's with the `itemsdiv` tags, and you realize you have syntax errors: `$('.item'.row')`? How about you just post a sample `return` and an HTML of *`exactly`* what you want it to look like?

Comment: Sorry i was so confused.. $room is $item i updated. And so many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow, but I'll try to work with you in this answer and get it straight. Best I can figure for now, you want something like the following:

```
var e = $('<div />', { id: "itemsdiv" }).appendTo('#step-1 .col-md-12'),
    r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d),
    i = 0;

$.each(r, function(k) {
    var id = this.ID,
        title = this.Title,
        price = this.Price,
        divItem = $('<div />', { "class": "item", id: "room" + i++ }).appendTo(e);

    divItem.append(
        $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: title })),
        $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: price })),
        $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: id }))
    );
});
```

Which would look like:

```js
var response = { d: JSON.stringify({ item1: { ID: 'id1', Title: 'title bla', Price: '$100.99' }, item2: { ID: 'id2', Title: 'title 2 bla', Price: '$9.99' }, item3: { ID: 'id3', Title: 'title bla 3', Price: '$99.99' } }) };

var e = $('<div />', { id: "itemsdiv" }).appendTo('#step-1 .col-md-12'),
 r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d),
 i = 0;

$.each(r, function(k) {
 var id = this.ID,
  title = this.Title,
  price = this.Price,
  divItem = $('<div />', { "class": "item", id: "room" + i++, text: 'Room # ' + i }).appendTo(e);
 
 divItem.append(
  $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: title })),
  $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: price })),
  $('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<div />', { "class": "col-xs-12", text: id }))
 );
});
```

```css
#step-1 { color: white; }
.item { background: blue; margin: .5em 1em; padding-left: 1em; }
.row { background: red; padding: .5em 1em; }
.row .col-xs-12 { border: 1px solid; }
.col-xs-12 { padding-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step-1"><div class="col-md-12"></div></div>
```